# At what point can I Encase a Eidolon?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, final-fantasy-explorers

In Final Fantasy Explorers, there's a quest called "Magicite Permit Exam" which is suppose to teach you how to encase Eidolons. (Monsters that are based on the summons from the FF Series)  The quest itself only gives you the clue that you need to use your Crystal Surge (CS) ability, (R+L when your resonance is over 100) and that the Eidolon needs to be low on health.

My question is:

**At what point is the is the Eidolon considered to be low on health?**

and/or:

**Is there a way to make sure that Encase comes up as a CS choice, or is there a way to shuffle the abilable CS's to re-roll for Encase to show up?**

Comment: +1. Sadly I don't have a full answer, but here's what I gathered so far: "Low health" appears to be Approximately 5-10% of the Eidolon's life. Encase seems to be a guaranteed CB **if and only if** you trigger one at or immediately before reaching this life point. Finally, if the Eidolon dies before you complete "Encase", you don't get it. This is hard to do with sufficiently powerful monster allies.

Comment: That last part is the hardest part about this too!  By the time they're low on health, Encase is up but I'm waiting for CB to come back, or trying to get my minions killed since Encase isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [twinfinite.net](http://twinfinite.net/2016/01/final-fantasy-explorers-how-to-encase-eidolons/)'s guide on how to encase eidolons:

> First, track down the Eidolon whose Magicite you want and whittle down their HP to less than a quarter. The idea is similar to catching Pokémon; the closer they are to being KO’d, the easier it is to encase them.

Therefore, it should be less than **25% of their max HP**

In order to be able to Encase,

> keep your Crystal Resonance above 100 by using plenty of abilities so you’ll have quick access to the Crystal Surge special attacks. Once you’ve got the Eidolon’s HP low enough, wait for your Crystal Surge abilities to reset. You can speed up this process by continuing to use abilities;

At which point

> when your Crystal Surge abilities re-activate, the top option should be “Encase.”

And you'll have sucessfully caught your Eidolon Magicite

Comment: Good find on the page! :)  Edit the answer to add the "How to recycle Crystal Surges" part and the +100 is yours.

Comment: Somehow I forgot that you mentioned : "Is there a way to make sure that Encase comes up as a CS choice, or is there a way to shuffle the abilable CS's to re-roll for Encase to show up?", else I would've in the first place. I've edited it in now